# angularjs extend promise with thenapply

Tags: angularjs, promise

In angularjs it is common that inside the **then** methode of the promise you need to make some changes to the scope, which requires you to wrap your code inside a $scope.$apply(...).
I was wondering if and how promises could be extended to provide a thenapply function, which would not require you anymore to do the wrapping, so instead of

```
myPromise.then(function() { $scope.$apply(function(data) { $scope.message=data.message; }) });
```

you could write:

```
myPromise.thenapply( function() { $scope.message=data.message; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `myPromise` is angular [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) promise you don't need to call `$scope.$apply` at all as `then` callback is executed in angular 'world' and changes to scope are propagated to all it's 'watchers'.

Of course I assume that you resolve your promise in angular $digest cycle. If not you need to call `$apply` when resolving promise.

If `myPromise` is different promise implementation, you always need to call $scope.$apply when resolving it just like with any other action done outside angular 'world', as angular doesn't know anything about it.

I wouldn't add `thenapply` method to promise as for me it encourages bad style of working with angular, just add `$apply` call somewhere where you resolve promise if it's outside angular $digest cycle.

Comment: It's a jquery promise, that is comming from signalr library. So I don't have control over it.

Comment: A jquery to angular promise convertor would maybe the solution, but it would not know how to write the code. Then one could write: .convert(jqueryPromise).then(function() { .... })